# Data is not captured in firestore react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore with react native like below, but while running my app data is not added to the cloud. am not sure why, please help me to understand the actual problem here.

```
componentWillMount() {
        console.log('Test1');

    firebase.initializeApp({
      apiKey: 'xxxxxxx',
      authDomain: 'testing-8ex763xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      databaseURL: 'https://testing-8e76xxxo.com',
      projectId: 'testing-xxxxx',
      storageBucket: 'testing-8xxxxx.com',
      messagingSenderId: '73664xxx042'
    });

    firebase.firestore().enablePersistence()
    .then(function() {
        // Initialize Cloud Firestore through firebase
        var db = firebase.firestore();
        console.log('Test3', db);

        db.collection('us').add({
            first: 'hai',
            last: '111',
            born: 1815
        })
        .then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        if (err.code == 'failed-precondition') {
            // Multiple tabs open, persistence can only be enabled
            // in one tab at a a time.
            // ...
        } else if (err.code == 'unimplemented') {
            // The current browser does not support all of the
            // features required to enable persistence
            // ...
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: i'm not getting any error messages, same time my data in not there in cloud firestore. no collection was created in cloud firestore. thanks for helping in this.

Comment: try moving `db.collection('us').add()` to outside `enablePersistence()` promise.

Comment: i tried that too Frank, (without enablePersistence) but no luck. still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have not given the reference of doc.
And also use 'set' instead of add method.

```
    db.collection('us').doc('some_name').set({
        first: 'hai',
        last: '111',
        born: 1815
    })
```